# Cannot read property 'style' of undefined React Material UI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-functional-component

I am trying to make a collapsible row inside a row. Basically I render a bunch of rows with pharmaceutical drugs, and I want someone to click on that row and it would show the description of that pharmaceutical drug.

I thought it was pretty straight forward but my code doesn't seem to work as I get the error I have described on my title.

Here's my code:

```
<TableContainer component={Paper} style={{overflow: "hidden"}}>
  <Table className={classes.table} aria-label="simple table">
    <TableHead>
      <TableRow>
        <TableCell />
        <TableCell><strong>Pharmaceutical Drug</strong></TableCell>
        <TableCell align="right"><strong>Drug Class</strong></TableCell>
        <TableCell align="right"><strong>Adult Dosage</strong></TableCell>
        <TableCell align="right"><strong>Pediatric Dosage</strong></TableCell>
        <TableCell align="right"><strong>Administration</strong></TableCell>
      </TableRow>
    </TableHead>
    <TableBody>
      {drugs.map((drug) => (
    <Slide direction="up" in={drugs} mountOnEnter unmountOnExit>
    <TableRow key={drug._id}>
        <TableCell>
      <IconButton aria-label="expand row" size="small" onClick={() => setOpen(!open)}>
        {open ? <KeyboardArrowUpIcon /> : <KeyboardArrowDownIcon />}
      </IconButton>
    </TableCell>
          <TableCell>{drug.name}</TableCell>
          <TableCell align="right">{drug.class}</TableCell>
          <TableCell align="right">{drug.suggestedDoseAdult}</TableCell>
          <TableCell align="right">{drug.suggestedDosePediatric}</TableCell>
          <TableCell align="right">{drug.administered}</TableCell>
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow>
    <TableCell style={{ paddingBottom: 0, paddingTop: 0 }} colSpan={6}>
      <Collapse in={open} timeout="auto" unmountOnExit>
        <Box margin={1}>
          <Typography variant="h6" gutterBottom component="div">
            {drug.description}
          </Typography>
        </Box>
      </Collapse>
    </TableCell>
  </TableRow>
        </Slide>
      ))}
    </TableBody>
  </Table>
</TableContainer>
```

Here's the error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined
(anonymous function)
node_modules/@material-ui/core/esm/Slide/Slide.js:214
  211 | }, other), function (state, childProps) {
  212 |   return /*#__PURE__*/React.cloneElement(children, _extends({
  213 |     ref: handleRef,
> 214 |     style: _extends({
      | ^  215 |       visibility: state === 'exited' && !inProp ? 'hidden' : undefined
  216 |     }, style, children.props.style)
  217 |   }, childProps));
```

Comment: Does the error say what line it pertains to? A sandbox would go a long way.

Comment: I have updated the main question with the error I get.

Comment: it looks like you are getting error because of  this line   <Slide direction="up" in={drugs} mountOnEnter unmountOnExit>

Comment: Yep, that was it, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to import TableContainer from Material UI. Just add this import to the top of your component file and you should be all set.

```
import { TableContainer } from '@material-ui/core';
```